# IBM Worklight - How to construct a JSON object in SQL adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-adapters

To construct a JSON object in a SQL adapter I have tried the following:

```
{
    'PatientID':4, 
    'FName':'test',
    'LName':'test',
    'AGE':1,
    'DOB':1988-09-01,
    'GENDER':'m',
    'BG':'A+'
}
```

However I get an error:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Method createSQLStatement was called inside a JavaScript function."
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMdy.png)
[image: how to construct Json oblect in sql Adapter in IBM Worklight]

Answer (score 2):

First, in the "Invoke Procedure Data" window for your adapter, don't wrap the object in quotes. If you do, it will think that the entire thing is a string.

If you remove the beginning and ending quotes then you almost have it correct. The window will take valid JSON objects, but only if all non integers are strings. Since 1988-09-01 is not a valid integer, it must be wrapped in quotes. You should be able to copy/paste this object into the wizard:

```
{
    'PatientID':4, 
    'FName':'test',
    'LName':'test',
    'AGE':1,
    'DOB':"1988-09-01",
    'GENDER':'m',
    'BG':'A+' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

createSQLStatement API should not be used inside of your functions. You it outside of functions, just like tutorial shows (slide 10) http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf